# How do you build a standalone external dependency js file for a library that has been modularised?

Tags: javascript, webpack, kendo-ui, browserify

Basically I have a number of legacy web applications that reference and use a library from a CDN ([Kendo UI](https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.624/js/kendo.all.min.js)). I have a task to remove such requests to remote hosts and so I'd like to encorporate the library into an existing npm script task that collects all dependencies into a single local js file which the application references.

The problem I'm having is that [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@progress/kendo-ui) does not provide pre-compiled js files that can be used immediately (unlike other libraries such as jquery or angular), but it is modularised and requires webpack or browserify to use it.

Since our legacy applications do not use the modular approach to loading dependencies, and I have no scope to rewrite them, I would like to somehow package the modularised library into an equivalent js file that will load the library so my application can access it simply via a `<script>` reference to it.

I have tried using browserify to compile from a source js file that contains simply a `require` reference to the library, but then referencing the compiled file in my application results in an error as the library's functions are not available to my application.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your on the right track using webpack, you just need to expose the library's.  If the lib is purely module based, you will have to make up your own global name,..eg. jQuery did jQuery & $, for your Kendo UI, maybe you could expose it to a global kendoUI, etc.

Comment: Thanks Keith. I'm not sure if it's just some quirk with kendo but it appears that the global variable `kendo` is set by the browserify compiled file I mentioned above, but that the jQuery extension functions (e.g. `$(...).kendoDropDownList()`) are not available globally (they are available inside of the js file that I compile with browserify). Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, you most likely have jQuery as a dependency inside the kendu UI.  As a default you would then end up with 2 versions of jQuery.  What you do here is setup webpack so that jQuery is an external.  Inside you webpack config, put `externals: { jquery: "jQuery" },.  Note the lowercase jquery, normally in node we keep require's lowercase, but if Kendu UI, does require('jQuery'), you will need to alter.

Comment: Just noticed your using browserfy, I'm not a browserfy user but it looks they call it shimming, so you can do it this way.  https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim

Comment: Brilliant Keith! I used webpack referencing jQuery in externals and now it works fine. If you want to add this as an answer then I'll give you the credit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using some library's that are module based, and you want to use them standalone, you will need to do 2 things.

1. expose the module to the global scope.  Maybe using the expose loader https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader or even just assign to the window object.
2. If the modules are also using a library that your also including standalone, you need to tell webpack about these,.

eg.

```
{
  externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery' 
  }
  // other stuff..
}
```

Finally when you include these, remember the ordering of your script tags.  eg. make sure you include jquery before your bundled javascript.